# How to get cloud function URL link?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

[image: CMD]

This is my code of cloud function. I'm using it if data in Firebase changes it notify users. I have already deployed the cloud function but it is not giving me any cloud function URL.

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.userStatusChange = functions.database.ref('/PatientReading/{$patient}/Humidty')
  .onWrite(event => {

    const original = event.data.val();
    const previous = event.data.previous.val();

    if (event.data.exists()) {
      var title = "User Signed IN";
      var body = "User " + original + " signed in";
    }

    var payload = {
      notification: {
        title: title,
        body: body
      }
    };

    var topic = "OnlineUsers";

    return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic, payload)
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
        return true;
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error sending message:", error);
        return true;
      });


  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is defining a Realtime Database trigger.  These functions only run in response to changes in the database at the path you specify.  These functions never have a URL - they can't be invoked directly.

If you need an URL to invoke some code in Cloud Functions, you will have to write an HTTP trigger.

Comment: So i can call it in android app ?

Comment: Sure, you can make a request to an HTTP endpoint from an Android app.

Comment: How to send that request i dont know about that ?

Comment: Hello, I believe that you are a little confused, what Doug is commenting is that if you want to call this from a http trigger you should create a function that works this way. You can check more information about cloud functions triggers at [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) and also here is information about http triggered cloud functions at [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events).

Hope you find this information useful.

Comment: i want if any data changes in realtime database it notify to users

Comment: So, based on what you commented, you would need to follow this documentation, but the trigger has a behavior as explained at the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events): "Waits for changes to a particular database location." and "Triggers when an event occurs and performs its tasks ", So you actually won't have a http endpoint to call, as the function will be triggered by the event.